# Defining a new color in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I am trying to learn ncurses and was wondering if I can create my own custom colors. I am aware that by using `init_color()`, I can modify any pre-defined colors in the ncurses library. But, is there a way I can define a new color with custom RGB values?

Comment: Terminal emulators tend to not support custom colours like you're asking about.  That's part of what makes them terminal emulators - they support ANSI colour behaviour, for example.  What is it you're trying to do, exactly?

Comment: @CarlNorum If I need to use a custom RGB value (that's not predefined in ncurses) in multiple places, is `init_color()` the only way of doing it?

Comment: @CarlNorum any decent terminal emulator supports many more colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`init_color()` is the only way to define new colors but the number of colors and color pairs available depends on the terminal you are using.

Many terminals can support up to 256 colors but on most systems the default TERM value is `xterm` which only supports 8.  xterm can be compiled with 256 color support and I think gnome-terminal supports 256.  Try changing your TERM enviroment variable to `xterm-256color` and check the COLORS variable in your ncurses program.