# Changing Color Definitions ncurses C

Tags: c, colors, ncurses

I am learning ncurses and I have made a little program and I want to fill my window with a color.

I want to fill it with a Red color but the default `COLOR_RED` is to bright and drives you crazy :)
Here is what I tried.

```
    WINDOW *wnd = initscr();

    start_color();

    init_color(COLOR_RED, 184, 142, 12);

    init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_RED);

    wbkgd(wnd, COLOR_PAIR(1));
    refresh();
```

How can I use a modified color ?

P.S : The code makes the background still the old `COLOR_RED`, not my modified one.

Comment: What terminal application are you using? Not all of them allow applications to set custom RGB colors.

Comment: your question seem's to be duplicated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341685/defining-a-new-color-in-ncurses

Comment: it's not duplicated, because there isn't any answer , i don't know how to define a new color. And how can i know what terminal am i using? i have ubuntu 14.04 gnome-terminal

Answer (score 2):

`init_color()` is how you create a color definition. However, you can only create "new" colors if your terminal supports more than 8 colors. Most terminals do, but do not enable this by default. To check, print the `COLORS` variable in the ncurses library like so:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
printw("My terminal supports %d colors.\n", COLORS);
```

If it comes out to be 8, you will only be able to modify the default colors instead of defining your own. To be able to define your own colors, you will need to use a terminal that supports more than 8 colors. To do this try the following on the command line:

```
echo $TERM
```

If this comes out to be `xterm-color`, then type the following at the command line to enable a 256 color terminal:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Then check the `COLORS` variable again. It should be updated to 256, provided all went well. You can now use `init_color()` to define your own colors.

More information on ncurses routines can be found here: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-Routine-Descriptions

Answer (score 0):

The only answer is init_color(). It's just that it doesn't work on most terminals (i.e. you're stuck with the original colors). You can check for the ability with can_change_color(), but that may not always be accurate, either.