# Having trouble with defining color values using init_color(); in ncurses in c

Tags: colors, ncurses, cs50, cc

I'm using `init_color();` in ncurses in C to try to define new RGB color values. However, `init_color();` does not take affect and change the default colors once I run the program.

I have tried moving around the `init_color();` statements before and after both the `init_pair();` statements and `start_color();` but have had no luck. I also have tried using different values (ASCII, and numbers from other sources) in place of ex. `COLOR_MAGENTA`, for the first argument in one of the `init_color();` statements, but also no luck. My `start_color();`, `init_color();` and `init_pair();` statements are all within a main function before the rest of the program. My terminal (using cloud9/cs50) supports 256 colors (checked using terminal commands). Also all color definitions are above function 'main'.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure that number of arguments is as expected
    if (argc != 1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./lemonade\n");
      return 1;
    }

// start up ncurses
if (!startup())
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error starting up ncurses\n");
    return 2;
}

// initialize colors
start_color();

// re-asign specific RGB value to colors
init_color(COLOR_MAGENTA, 254, 160, 207);
init_color(COLOR_GREEN, 37, 244, 82);
init_color(COLOR_BLUE, 96, 82, 186);

// used cyan for a different greeen
init_color(COLOR_CYAN, 46, 243, 74);

// used yellow for a grey
init_color(COLOR_YELLOW, 156, 156, 156);

// used red for a purple
init_color(COLOR_RED, 208, 196, 253);

// initilaize color pairs
init_pair(LOGO_PAIR, COLOR_MAGENTA, COLOR_GREEN);
init_pair(DRAWBORDERSSPECIAL_PAIR, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_GREEN);
init_pair(BORDERS_PAIR, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);
init_pair(SPECIALNEXT_PAIR, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_GREEN);
init_pair(SUNNYBLUE_PAIR, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLUE);
init_pair(WEATHERGREEN_PAIR, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_CYAN);
init_pair(CLOUDYGREY_PAIR, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_YELLOW);
init_pair(HOTPURPLE_PAIR, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_RED);

// clean
clean();            // clean includes (refresh(); and clear();)

// draw borders
drawborders();

// run screen 1
screenone();





// support color test                           
mvprintw(6, 50, "My terminal supports %d colors.", COLORS);

// has_color(); test    
if (has_colors() == FALSE)
{
    mvprintw(7, 50, "Your terminal does not support color \n");
}

// can_change_color(); test     
if (can_change_color() == FALSE)
{
    mvprintw(8, 50, "Can_change_color is false \n");
}
```

I expected the `init_color();` statements to take affect and change the default colors (Ex. Magenta, black, etc.) to the newly assigned specific RGB values, but they remain the same once the program runs.

I added checks to the number of colors supported, `has_colors();`, and `can_change_color();`. The number of colors support returns 8, `has_colors();` returns true, and finally `can_change_color();` returns false. Thank you for suggesting using `has_colors();` and `can_change_color();` although this seems to be the issue I'm not sure where to go from here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Color Definitions ncurses C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642696/changing-color-definitions-ncurses-c)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I cannot see your calls to `has_colors()` and `can_change_color()`, which should be used to detect if you're even *allowed* to do this on your system?

This is the *first* thing you should be checking. It may be that color changing is *not* permitted in your environment.

Comment: Currently ```can_change_color();``` returns true, as does ``has_color();```. I used the terminal command "echo $TERM" and received 'xterm-256color'. I also used "tput colors" and received '256'. I'm not sure why the ```init_color();``` statements won't take effect even thought the terminal supports 256 color?