# Coloured cout not working XCode macOS 12.0.1

Tags: c++

I am currently coding a version of Wordle in C++.

I am trying to change the colour of text for outputs and I have no idea why this is not working.

Any help is much appreciated!
Washy x

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RESET   "\033[0m"
#define BOLDGREEN   "\033[1m\033[32m"      /* Bold Green */
#define BOLDYELLOW  "\033[1m\033[33m"      /* Bold Yellow */


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cout << "Welcome to WORDLE" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Guess the WORDLE in six tries. \n\nEach guess must be a valid five-letter word. Hit the enter button to submit. \n\nAfter each guess, the color of the tiles will change to show how close your guess was to the word." << endl << endl;
    
    
    cout << BOLDGREEN << "hello" << RESET << endl;
```

EDIT:

Here is the output:

Welcome to WORDLE

Guess the WORDLE in six tries.

Each guess must be a valid five-letter word. Hit the enter button to submit.

After each guess, the color of the tiles will change to show how close your guess was to the word.

[1m[32mhello[0m

Comment: terminal control codes are not Standardized, unfortunately

Comment: The control characters are dependent on the shell that is displaying them. You can look at `curses` or `ncurses` packages which tries to detect the underlying shell and generate the appropriate control characters for the underlying shell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27642696/14065