# Custom RGB colors with Python curses

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I'm writing a program in Python using the `curses` module in the standard library.

I want my program to just exit if it can't use custom colors I specify with RGB triples.

So I have some starter code that looks like:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
  if not curses.can_change_color():
    raise Exception('Cannot change color')

  curses.init_color(curses.COLOR_BLACK, 999,   0,   0)
  curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
  curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
  stdscr.addstr('hello', curses.color_pair(1))
  stdscr.addstr(' world', curses.color_pair(2))
  stdscr.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

And the result I get is:

[image]

I expected the black to be replaced by red.

Am I misunderstanding the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.init_color)? How can I get `curses` to respect custom RGB colors I want to use? Or at least fail and tell me that the terminal doesn't support it?

The docs for curses [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/init_color) seem to suggest that on failure it will return an error, and the CPython source seems to [propagate curses errors](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d264235f6e066611b412f7c2e1603866e0f7f1b/Modules/_cursesmodule.c) pretty faithfully.

In case it is relevant, I'm on OS X 10.11, and I'm testing on Python3 I installed with Homebrew. But I get the same effect with OS X's builtin Python interpreter as well.

EDIT:

Slightly modified sample code to display color content:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
  if not curses.can_change_color():
    raise Exception('Cannot change color')

  stdscr.addstr(1, 0, repr(curses.color_content(curses.COLOR_BLACK)))
  curses.init_color(curses.COLOR_BLACK, 999,   0,   0)
  curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
  curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
  stdscr.addstr(0, 0, 'hello', curses.color_pair(1))
  stdscr.addstr(' world', curses.color_pair(2))
  stdscr.addstr(2, 0, repr(curses.color_content(curses.COLOR_BLACK)))
  stdscr.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

The result this time is:
[image]

Comment: Can you check a before/after with [`curses.color_content`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.color_content)?

Comment: @RadLexus The color content seems to be updated, it's set to (0, 0, 0) before, and when checked again is set to (999, 0, 0)

Comment: Isn't `curses` supposed to only support, like, 16 basic colors like terminals did when it was designed?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: `curses` is just a wrapper around ncurses these days, which is much more capable.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341685/defining-a-new-color-in-ncurses

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: that answer suggests changing a default `TERM`, but mine is already set to `TERM=xterm-256color` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @math4tots which `curses` wrapper package are you using? In PyPI, there's at least a dozen.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Im using the default one that comes installed when you install Python on a Mac. The source for it lives in the CPython repo. Not sure if every standard lib module comes by default in Linux distros tho

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot may be of Terminal.app; in a quick check it does not honor the escape sequences used for changing color.  On the other hand, iTerm2 does use those escape sequences.

If you're using Terminal.app, setting `TERM` to xterm-256color is pointless, due to the large number of differences versus xterm.  There's [discussion](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Terminal_app) in the terminal database as commentary that you may find interesting.

The relevant features which curses uses to decide if the terminal can change color are `ccc` and `initc`. Those capabilities are not defined in the [`nsterm`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-nsterm) terminal descriptions. The terminal descriptions use the [`xterm+256setaf`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_256setaf) building block rather than [`xterm+256color`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_256color), which `infocmp` shows are different:

```
    comparing xterm+256setaf to xterm+256color.
        comparing booleans.
            ccc: F:T.
        comparing numbers.
        comparing strings.
            initc: NULL, '\E]4;%p1%d;rgb\:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\E\\'.
            oc: NULL, '\E]104\007'.
            op: '\E[39;49m', NULL.
```

Comment: I'm outside at the moment so will test it when I get back, but if I remember the docs right, I think wrapper calls start_color if it is supported in the current env